# Some weights of the model checkpoint at vinai/phobert-base were not used when initializing RobertaModel:

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

My PC is Windows 11 pro x64, NVIDIA card, Python 3.10 , pip . I follow guide at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/phobert

my command

```
pip install jupyterlab
pip list
python -m jupyterlab
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
pip install transformer
```

my code

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

phobert = AutoModel.from_pretrained("vinai/phobert-base")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/phobert-base")
line = "Tôi là sinh_viên trường đại_học Công_nghệ ."
input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(line)])
with torch.no_grad():
    features = phobert(input_ids)
```

error

```py
Some weights of the model checkpoint at vinai/phobert-base were not used when initializing RobertaModel: ['lm_head.decoder.bias', 'lm_head.bias', 'lm_head.layer_norm.weight', 'lm_head.dense.weight', 'lm_head.dense.bias', 'lm_head.decoder.weight', 'lm_head.layer_norm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing RobertaModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing RobertaModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
```

[image]

How to run success?

Comment: That is not an error message. Your model was loaded correctly. The message just indicates that the state_dict contains more weights that your current class can not load.